# VS2010: Does "Build Solution" build the solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build

My **Build** menu contains two build options:

- Build Solution
- Build *MyProjectName*

[image]

If i select **Build Solution** (then **Debug**, **Start Debugging (F5)**), the running executable does not contain my code logic, or visual form changes.

If i select **Build *MyProjectName*** (then **Debug**, **Start Debugging (F5)**), my changes **do** exist in the executable.

It's almost as though **Build Solution** doesn't *build* the *solution*, but instead builds something else.

In Visual Studio 2010, does "**Build Solution**" build the solution?

---

### Bonus Question

How do i customize the **Build** menu so it contains additional options that i'd like:

[image]

Comment: If you right-click the solution, click Properties, then go to "Configuration Properties," are your projects included in the current solution configuration?

Comment: That's a pretty broken Build menu.  Tools + Import and Export, Reset sounds advisable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any version of Visual Studio "Build Solution" means build solution. You might have invalid project configuration. Please, make sure that you have checked your project in Configuration Manager:

1. Select the solution node from the **Solution Explorer**
2. In the **Project** menu select **Properties**
3. On the left select **Configuration Properties**
4. Ensure all project in the solution have the **Build** column checked

[image: Configuration Manager]

Comment: That was the secret sauce i was missing. i have 3 projects, and the important one was unchecked.